# While Loop with Multiple String Conditions Cannot Leave Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I am new to Python and I am doing some projects to try and learn it. I am trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game to learn conditions and loops. I have a function in my game called "validator" that has a while loop with 4 string conditions however when I try to reassign that variable to break the loop it still gives me my error message that I built in saying "Please enter a valid response".

How do I get the while loop to end and return the variable ans?

Thank you for your help,

-Crow

```
# Rock Paper Scissors Game
import random

# Makes the Player Choose a Valid Answer Function
def validator():
    ans = input()
    while ans != "Rock" or "Paper" or "Scissors" or "QUIT":
        ans = input("Please enter a valid response: ")
    else:
        return ans

# Comp Choosers Function

def compcho():
    v = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if v == 1:
        return "Rock"
    if v == 2:
        return "Paper"
    if v == 3:
        return "Scissors"


# Win decider
def decider(man, pc):
    if man == pc:
        return "It's a tie! " + man + " to " + pc + "!"
    elif man != pc:
        if man == "Rock" and pc == "Scissors":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " beats the PC's choice of " + pc + "! Player Victory!"
        if man == "Rock" and pc == "Paper":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " loses to the PC's choice of " + pc + ". Player Defeat."
        if man == "Scissors" and pc == "Rock":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " loses to the PC's choice of " + pc + ". Player Defeat."
        if man == "Scissors" and pc == "Paper":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " beats the PC's choice of " + pc + "! Player Victory!"
        if man == "Paper" and pc == "Rock":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " beats the PC's choice of " + pc + "! Player Victory!"
        if man == "Paper" and pc == "Scissors":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " loses to the PC's choice of " + pc + ". Player Defeat."
        if man == "Quit":
            print("Goodbye")
        else:
            print("Hmm I wasn't expecting " + man + ".")


# Program Start

print("Welcome to the Rock Paper Scissors Game!")
choice = "ham"
while choice != "Quit":

    # Chooser
    print("Please Enter Rock Paper Scissors or Quit")

    valans = validator()

    pcpick = compcho()

    print(decider(valans, pcpick))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your condition like this (repeat the variable name and check your logical operators) :

```
while ans != "Rock" and ans != "Paper" and ans != "Scissors" and ans != "QUIT":
```

or use 'in' :

```
while ans not in ["Rock","Paper","Scissors","QUIT"] :
```

Comment: I used your first solution and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!  Well done on writing a well formed quesiton.

The issue you are having here has to do with how conditional expressions are evaluated.  The way you have it now, Python is doing this:

```py
while (ans != "Rock") or ("Paper") or ("Scissors") or ("QUIT")
```

In this situation, the strings "Paper", "Scissors", and "Quit" themselves always evaluate to true.  You can see that here:

```py
>>> bool("Rock")
True
```

What you want here is:

```py
while ans not in ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "QUIT"]:
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware this was a way to write out that condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one of your functions return a value of `"Quit"` and set the variable `choice` with it. I'm not at my personal computer right now so I'm going to answer with mostly your code.. maybe later I'll come back and edit with things cleaned up a bit more..

```py
# Rock Paper Scissors Game
import random

# Makes the Player Choose a Valid Answer Function
def validator():
    ans = input()
    while ans != "Rock" or "Paper" or "Scissors" or "QUIT":
        ans = input("Please enter a valid response: ")
    else:
        return ans

# Comp Choosers Function

def compcho():
    v = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if v == 1:
        return "Rock"
    if v == 2:
        return "Paper"
    if v == 3:
        return "Scissors"


# Win decider
def decider(man, pc):
    if man == pc:
        return "It's a tie! " + man + " to " + pc + "!"
    elif man != pc:
        if man == "Rock" and pc == "Scissors":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " beats the PC's choice of " + pc + "! Player Victory!"
        if man == "Rock" and pc == "Paper":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " loses to the PC's choice of " + pc + ". Player Defeat."
        if man == "Scissors" and pc == "Rock":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " loses to the PC's choice of " + pc + ". Player Defeat."
        if man == "Scissors" and pc == "Paper":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " beats the PC's choice of " + pc + "! Player Victory!"
        if man == "Paper" and pc == "Rock":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " beats the PC's choice of " + pc + "! Player Victory!"
        if man == "Paper" and pc == "Scissors":
            return "The player's choice of " + man + " loses to the PC's choice of " + pc + ". Player Defeat."
        if man == "Quit":
            print("Goodbye")
            # Must return a value here... 
            return "Quit"
        else:
            print("Hmm I wasn't expecting " + man + ".")
            # doesn't matter what gets returned here based on your other code so lets return "Keep Playing" for consistency 
            return "Keep Playing"


# Program Start

print("Welcome to the Rock Paper Scissors Game!")
choice = "ham"
while choice != "Quit":

    # Chooser
    print("Please Enter Rock Paper Scissors or Quit")

    valans = validator()

    pcpick = compcho()
 
    choice = decider(valans, pcpick) # see we set choice to the value of the decided function. 
    print(choice)
    # now the loop will have a condition that will cause it to exit.
```